# Log profile tab in worklight console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

In worklight console, i have this log profiles tab. Why and how to use the Log profile tab in worklight console. I went throught the document couldnt find any link regarding that. Please provide me some links regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

The Log Profiles tab that you are referring to is explained in the following Getting Started tutorial: [Remote controlled client-side log collection](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/advanced-client-side-development/remote-controlled-client-side-log-collection/).

[image]

In the Log Profiles tab you will be able to review and act upon the various data that you can collect from devices running your application.